# Ice cream sandwich - Full Screen is not working

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-fullscreen

I am implementing a launcher. I want to disable back/home/settings button on the screen for a while. Therefore I want to set it as full screen. I could do that in gingerbread and honeycomb, it works fine but in ice cream sandwich it does not. I have tried below codes, neither it works.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Also I have set theme as fullscreen in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">` in your manifest

Comment: That does not hide the home, back, menu button. It will just hide the default grey title bar...

Answer (score 0):

Icecream sandwitch support the code you posted . may be its problem with your device .try the same code

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

with only an imageview in your xml .Try to run that

Comment: I have tried that too. It is not working.Then I have read api for ice cream. It says using getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE); makes the system bar invisible  but if the user interacts with the screen, it appears again. This has answered my question, thank you though

Answer (score -1):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I am using Ice Cream Sandwich and it works fine for me. There's some other problem in your app.

Comment: copying code from question and adding "it works for me" is not an answer

Comment: Its not problem of icecream sandwitch thats what i mean . i hav my own app which use this code and my phone is micromax a68 android 4.0.4. need any more @selvin